# How to update memcached server in Linux

Tags: java, linux, bash, memcached

I have installed memcahced server in my machine

```
namal@namal:~$ sudo service memcached start
Starting memcached: memcached.

namal@namal:~$ telnet 127.0.0.1 11211
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.

version
VERSION 1.4.14

namal@namal:~$ which memcached
/usr/bin/memcached
```

So, I wanted to update it into 1.4.17 since it is the latest one.
But, when I say `yum update memcached`, it yells like this.

```
Setting up the Update Process
No Match for argument: memcached
No package memcached available.
No Packages marked for Update
```

OS : Ubuntu 12.10

Result for `aptitude show memcached` command

```
namal@namal:~$ aptitude show memcached
Package: memcached                
State: installed
Automatically installed: no
Version: 1.4.14-0ubuntu1
Priority: optional
Section: web
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: i386
Uncompressed Size: 226 k
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4), libevent-2.0-5 (>= 2.0.10-stable), libsasl2-2 (>= 2.1.24), perl, lsb-base (>= 3.2-13), adduser
Suggests: libcache-memcached-perl, libmemcached
Description: A high-performance memory object caching system
 Danga Interactive developed memcached to enhance the speed of LiveJournal.com, a site which was already doing 20 million+ dynamic page views per day for 1 million users with a bunch of webservers and a bunch of database servers. memcached dropped
 the database load to almost nothing, yielding faster page load times for users, better resource utilization, and faster access to the databases on a memcache miss. 

 memcached optimizes specific high-load serving applications that are designed to take advantage of its versatile no-locking memory access system. Clients are available in several different programming languages, to suit the needs of the specific
 application. Traditionally this has been used in mod_perl apps to avoid storing large chunks of data in Apache memory, and to share this burden across several machines.
Homepage: http://www.danga.com/memcached/
```

Comment: Your using yum on Ubuntu ?

Comment: try: 

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install memcached`

Comment: thanx Alexandr. But still it says VERSION 1.4.14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running `aptitude show memcached` in the terminal. Then you might find out that the latest version currently supported by the Ubuntu 12.10 repositories is in fact 1.4.14. (You might need to install aptitude if it's not installed.)

That is because the package is maintained by the Ubuntu developers to ensure that it is stable for the Ubuntu release you are using. For more about Ubuntu repositories, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

If you still want the latest and greatest, you might need to build it from source yourself: <s>https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewInstallFromSource</s>

**Edit:** Broken link, and no way to substitute it. Their wiki docs seems to be suffering after Memcached migrated to GitHub. So http://www.memcached.org/ or https://github.com/memcached/memcached might be the place to start. Hopefully, up to date install-from-source-docs will eventually show up at https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki.

Comment: Thnk you HrKristiansen for the information. I installed and run the aptitude. It doesn't show that latest version currently supported by the Ubuntu 12.10 repositories is 1.4.14. How can I get it. I have add the result for aptitude command FYR. What am I missing here?

Comment: Reading the aptitude output, it seems to me that `Version: 1.4.14-0ubuntu1` is what you are looking for.

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6284/check-package-version-using-apt-get-aptitude

Comment: True enough! "0ubuntu1 is a special case, as it's used as a revision that indicates that it's not based on any Debian package of that upstream version." [ref : http://askubuntu.com/questions/26507/whats-the-significance-of-0ubuntu1-at-the-end-of-a-package-version-string]. Again thank you!

Comment: Hi Erlend Kristiansen,

The link to the memcached docs seems to be broken. Could you please provide us the current live link if you are aware of the same?

P.S : The docs on the official website link to the same destination, which is also broken.

Answer (score 3):

From Memcached's site: https://memcached.org/downloads

```
wget http://memcached.org/latest
tar -zxvf latest
cd memcached-1.x.x
./configure && make && make test && sudo make install
```